# Right-align a multicolumn table header that stretched over a left-aligned column

Tags: multicolumn, dcolumn

I am trying to right-align a multicolumn table heading, where one of the columns it straddles is aligned on a decimal point with dcolumn, and the other is left-aligned. In the example below, I would like the closing bracket of "Difference (p-value)" to be flush with the closing brackets of the column below it. I have fiddled with spacing between columns and creative mixing of the general alignment  "rcl"  etc. Does anyone have other tips?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{Q}{D{.}{.}{2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lQQQ@{\hspace{0.1em}}l}
  \hline
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Period 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Period 2} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{Difference (p-value)}  \\ 
  \hline
 var0 & 6.00 & 8.00 & 2.00 & (0.00) \\ 
  var1 & 0.61 & 0.73 & 0.12 & (0.00) \\ 
   var2 & 359.00 & 404.00 & 44.43 & (0.03) \\ 

   \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have specific reasons  for such a thin space between columns  3 and 4?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  What meaning has numbers in the last(fifth) column? Are they uncertainty of values in the fourth column? If they are, they notation is wrong, on such a way they can not be decimal numbers. With decimal numbers you can write  as for example `2.00 \pm 0.00`.

Comment: Thanks  for the questions. The numbers in parantheses are p-values from a t-test of the difference between the columns. I  do not want them to be separate columns because there are a few tables where I will have more than one of these difference(p-value) columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some guessing what you like to have (with use of the `siunitx` package instead of `dcolumn`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}
                      S[table-format=2.2(1),
                        table-alignment=right,
                        separate-uncertainty,
                        ] 
                }
  \hline
  Variable  & {Period 1} & {Period 2} & {Difference (p-value)}  \\
  \hline
 var0       &   6.00    &   8.00    &  2.00(0)   \\
 var1       &   0.61    &   0.73    &  0.12(0)   \\
 var2       & 359.00    & 404.00    & 44.43(3)   \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}
                      S[table-format=2.2(1),
                        table-alignment=right,
                        ]
                }
  \hline
  Variable  & {Period 1} & {Period 2} & {Difference (p-value)}  \\
  \hline
 var0       &   6.00    &   8.00    &  2.00(0)   \\
 var1       &   0.61    &   0.73    &  0.12(0)   \\
 var2       & 359.00    & 404.00    & 44.43(3)   \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}
                      S[table-format=8.0,
                        ]
                      %@{\hskip-2em}
                      S[table-format=1.2,
                        table-space-text-pre=\,(,
                        table-space-text-post=),
                        input-symbols = {( )}
                        ]
                }
  \hline
  Variable  & {Period 1} & {Period 2} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{Difference (p-value)}  \\
  \hline
 var0       &   6.00    &   8.00    &  2.00 & (0.00)   \\
 var1       &   0.61    &   0.73    &  0.12 & (0.00)   \\
 var2       & 359.00    & 404.00    & 44.43 & (0.03)   \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Correct notations are in the first two examples.

[image]

However, I would wrote p value as separate column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l *{2}{ S[table-format=3.2] }
                            S[table-format=2.2]
                            S[table-format=1.2,
                              table-space-text-pre={\,(},
                              table-space-text-post=),
                              input-symbols = {( )}]
                            }
  \hline
  Variable  & {Period 1} & {Period 2} & {Difference} & {(p-value)}  \\
  \hline
 var0       &   6.00    &   8.00    &  2.00 & (0.00)   \\
 var1       &   0.61    &   0.73    &  0.12 & (0.00)   \\
 var2       & 359.00    & 404.00    & 44.43 & (0.03)   \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Versions 2 and 3  get to what I want.